# How to select network interface when connecting to SFTP with JSch

Tags: java, bind, sftp, jsch

I am facing problem to create a session to a remote SFTP server by JSch:

The command i use to connect the sftp server through shell is:

```
sftp -o BindAddress=SOME_IP_ADDRRESS myUserName@HOST_IP_ADDR
```

and its working fine, but when I am trying with Java (JSch) then I am getting a timeout exception. The Java code is

```
/* KEY_FILE_NAME = is a file with rsa public key */
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(KEY_FILE_NAME).getFile());
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity(file.getAbsolutePath());
Properties hash = new Properties();
hash.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
logger.debug("SSh Server Host name >>" + SSH_SERVER_HOST_NAME + " || User Name >>" +  SSH_SERVER_USER_NAME);

session = jsch.getSession(SSH_SERVER_USER_NAME, SSH_SERVER_HOST_NAME);
UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.setConfig(hash);
session.setPort(22);
session.setTimeout(45000);
session.connect();
```

The exception I am getting is :

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established

I guess its coming as I am not setting the `BindAddress` with `-o` option which I am using while I am using the shell command. If that is the case then how to set the `-o BindAddress` parameter in JSch? Or am I doing something wrong, please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there's an explicit support for selecting a network interface to connect from in JSch.

But you can implement a [`SocketFactory`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SocketFactory.html) interface, such as that it creates a `Socket` instance using the [constructor overload with the `localAddr`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket-java.net.InetAddress-int-java.net.InetAddress-int-):

```
public Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

(use 0 for the `localPort`)

Then pass the factory to the [`Session.setSocketFactory()`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setSocketFactory-com.jcraft.jsch.SocketFactory-) before calling the `connect()` and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you for everything. I am trying out the solution and will update.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the solution , I added the following code before calling `session.connect()`.

```
session.setSocketFactory(new SocketFactory() 
{
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    public InputStream getInputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException 
    {
        if (in == null)
            in = socket.getInputStream();
        return in;
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException 
    {
        if (out == null)
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        return out;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
    {
       // The IP Addresses are changed ....
       // using the original IP in my code
        byte[] remoteIpAddr = new byte[] { (byte) 11,(byte) 11, 11, 11 }; 
        byte[] localIpAddr = new byte[] { 55, 55, 55, 55 };

        InetAddress remoteIp = InetAddress.getByAddress(remoteIpAddr);
        InetAddress localIp = InetAddress.getByAddress(localIpAddr);

        logger.debug("remoteIp >>" + remoteIp.toString());
        logger.debug("localIp >>" + localIp.toString());
        Socket socket = new Socket(remoteIp, 22, localIp, 0);
        logger.debug("socket created >> " + socket.toString());
        return socket;
    }
});
```

And its creating the socket : checked the log file for >>

```
logger.debug("socket created >> " + socket.toString());
```

But now I am getting an exception :

**Auth cancel**

What may be the cause , The key which I have is a **id_rsa.pub** file, which starts with

```
ssh-rsa AXTYU....
```

and I have created the private key file from this file through keygen which I am using in my `session.addIdentity()` method, the format of the private key is :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
KIOPU.....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Am i missing something , please suggest...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Though, start new question for new problems. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Note that you should use `host` and `port` parameters of `createSocket`, instead of hard-coding them into method implementation.

Comment: Hi Martin : Thanks a lot for your help, now my code is working fine.. the mistake I have made that I was using the wrong private key file. The previous code is working fine. Just chnage the key content and chane the private key file name from id_rsa.pub to id_rsa.

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to bind to a specific address (and port, should to need to):

```
class MySocketFactory implements SocketFactory {

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("1.1.1.1", 0));
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        return socket.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        return socket.getOutputStream();
    }

}
```

I validated this using `netstat -an` on my Linux box and observed the local side of the connection was bound to 1.1.1.1 with an ephemeral port number (I temporarily set up an interface with this address).

I set the factory immediately before calling `session.connect()`:

```
SocketFactory sfactory = new MySocketFactory();
session.setSocketFactory(sfactory);

session.connect();
```