# bind to local address for SFTP

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel in a multi-homed environment. Therefore I need to specify which local address should be used as the source address when building outbound SFTP connections. I did not find any configuration to do so, the only way I currently see is to write a proxy which simple opens the TCP connection using the correct local address and provide that to Camel.

Are there any obvious ways besides that which I probably simply missed?

Thanks for your help,
Heri

Comment: which version of camel you are using. from 2.23 onwards there is a configuration property bindAddress which you bind your source address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution in Camel.

Camel uses [Jsch component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jsch/src/main/docs/scp-component.adoc) to make SFTP connections.

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559957/how-to-select-network-interface-when-connecting-to-sftp-with-jsch) implies that it is also not possible out-of-the-box when you use Jsch directly.

Perhaps you can adapt the solution from the question/answer link above.