# Use a bind address with Jsch Session

Tags: java, jsch

I am attempting to set an address so that when I leave my server to scp a file I am not leaving as the servers hostname I am leaving as a different ip. The linux side of things is all setup. I can run the following ssh command and everything works as expected.

```
ssh -b 1.1.1.1 testuser@sshhost
```

My issue is now I am attemtpting to use JSch to scp the files over, but I can't figure out the correct session setup. I am using public private keys and those works correctly. Below is my current process.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Keypair keyPair = KeyPair.load(jsch, privateKey, publicKey);
boolean keyPairdecrpy = keyPair.decrypt(passphrase);
if(keyPairdecrpy)
{
    jsch.addIdentity(privateKey, passphrase);
}
Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "sshhost", 22);
Properties config new Properties();
config.put("StrickHostKeyChecking:, "no");
config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect(timeout);
```

So the things I've tried so far.

1. Creating a Socket Factory setting the bind address and then running

   ```
   InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSicketAddress("1.1.1.1", 0);
   Socket socket = new Socket(sshhost, 22);
   socket.bind(addr);
   session.setSocketFactory((SocketFactory) socket);
   ```
2. Attempted to use the build in port forwarding with the Session Class

   ```
   session.setPortForwardingL(0, "1.1.1.1", 22);
   ```

Comment: Yes/No. same answer different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following `SocketFactory` worked for me:

```
class MySocketFactory implements SocketFactory {

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("1.1.1.1", 0));
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        return socket.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        return socket.getOutputStream();
    }

}
```

I validated this using `netstat -an` on my Linux box and observed the local side of the connection was bound to 1.1.1.1 with an ephemeral port number (I temporarily set up an interface with this address).

I set the factory immediately before calling `session.connect()`:

```
SocketFactory sfactory = new MySocketFactory();
session.setSocketFactory(sfactory);

session.connect();
```

Comment: Thank you. Man I was spending so long just making a Socket. Thanks for spelling it out.

Comment: Cool holler if you need anything else! I'm using JSch for a proof of concept exercise right now and going through the same motions you are!

Comment: Please consider moving your good answer to [How to select network interface when connecting to SFTP with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26559957/850848) and vote for this question to be closed as a duplicate.